# Java crashing? Using OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Lately whenever I run my OpenGL game I get this strange error:

I am on OS X.

What does this error mean?

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00000001276eff9f, pid=461, tid=5379
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_11-b12) (build 1.8.0_11-b12)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.11-b03 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [GLEngine+0x15bf9f]  gleRunVertexSubmitImmediate+0x27ef
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/amit/workspace/Evox Voxel Engine GL 2.1/hs_err_pid461.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

This error is generated whenever I draw:

```
            GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, indicesCount,
                    GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

Comment: What is the code producing this error?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo It happens when I try to draw to the screen.. This didn't happen until i started increasing the amount of chunks I render... Also now its happening even if I am rendering only 4 chunks which it used to work with before..

Comment: Well, have you tried what is says? Have you tried `ulimit -c unlimited`?

Comment: @1337 Yes. Doesn't affect anything.

Comment: Well. You crashed the GL implemenation. Java's safeguards won't work in a case where a native library is called. But the crash does not mean that this is the GL implementation's fault. There are tons of reasons why this particular draw call might crash.  Your vertex attributes might be not set up properly, your indices count is wriong, you don't have an `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` bound when trying to call that, your data types are wrong...

Comment: @derhass Posted what my problem was. Hopes this would help anyone else who is into OpenGL programming and gets this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This was my problem:**

I was using a global Indices VBO for all chunks because I figured it wouldn't matter if I draw a bit more indices than I would actually have. Turns out this causes some kind of buffer overflow or reading/writing to an invalid address that causes the entire game to crash.

*So the lesson is always calculate EXACTLY the amount of indices that you have for EACH object and then supply that to the draw method, otherwise it could cause weird behaviour.*

Also another possible problem would be that your indices VBO is limited by the type of it, for example byte/short/int. This could cause your game to crash if your indices go over the amount that a byte/short/int can hold.

Happy programming.